# how to restrict HTTP requests for an application in Mulesoft?

Tags: mule-studio

How to restrict only 10 requests for an application in MuleSoft and should send an alert message if the 11th request is sent to application so that we can prevent server crash?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply below out-of the box mule policies to restrict the HTTP based API call.

**Rate Limiting**-
The number of messages processed by an API per time period is rate limited at a maximum value specified in the policy. The rate limiting is applied to all API calls, regardless of the source. Any messages beyond the maximum are rejected.

**Rate Limiting – SLA-Based**-
The number of messages per time period processed by an API is rate limited at a maximum value specified in the SLA tier. Any messages beyond the maximum are rejected. Enforcement is based on the client ID passed in the request.

For more details you check this out-

https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/rate-limiting-and-throttling

https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/rate-limiting-and-throttling-sla-based-policies

Answer (score 1):

Mulesoft anypoint platform is really powerful. 
you can set up the Rate Limiting policy to restrict the no of API calls.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the details

https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/rate-limiting-and-throttling

If you are using API Manager using Anypoint platform then it will be very easy to use the out of box policies to enforce on the APIs.